# Evaluating ksmooth at a point?

Tags: r, kernel, regression

so i'm trying to find a way to evaluate a point on the estimated curve fitted to a dataset using k-smooth. ie i've already fitted a curve for dataset using kernel reg. and want to estimate the values on the curve at specific points. like i have a graph with the curve... bu ti'm not sure how to go about using it.

Sorry if it isn't too clear... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To extract other points, a simple (although inefficient way), would just be to specify the `n.point` argument. For example,

```
z = ksmooth(cars$speed, cars$dist, "normal", bandwidth = 5, n.points = 1000)
```

will output 1000 values starting at `min(cars$speed)` and ending at `max(cars$speed)`. You can access these values via:

```
z$x 
z$y
```

**Example**

Suppose you wanted to get the point prediction for `x=21`. Then you select the find the `x` value that is closet to `21`:

```
which.min(abs(z$x-21))
```

then use this index to select the particular `y` value

```
z$y[which.min(abs(z$x-21))]
```

Comment: okay, i'm still kindof confused as to how do i choose an x in z$x and find out which y matches it in z$y?

Answer (score 0):

In the other answer, there may not be an x-value equal to exactly 21. In the actual fitting, you can specify the `x.points` argument to get the points you want the fit evaluated at.

```
z = ksmooth(cars$speed, cars$dist, "normal", bandwidth = 5, x.points = 21)
print(z)

$x
[1] 21
$y
[1] 58.00075
```